# inputs stream to get json example and print

Tags: java

I´m having a trouble in the line `InputStream is= JSONjava.class.getResourceAsStream ( "JSONexample.json"); String JSONexample = IOUtils.toString( is );`, i tried to put in the imports "import sun.misc.IOUtils;" but it doesn´t work, any help will be useful, thanks.

```
import java.io.InputStream;
import org.json.JSONObject;    
import sun.misc.IOUtils;

public class JSONjava {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        InputStream is = JSONjava.class.getResourceAsStream( "JSONexample.json");
        String JSONexample = IOUtils.toString( is );

        JSONObject json = (JSONObject) JSONSerializer.toJSON( JSONexample ); 
        JSONObject slides = json.getJSONObject("pilot");

        String name = slides.getString("name");
        String desc = slides.getString("desc");

        System.out.println( "Name: " + name );
        System.out.println( "Description: " + desc );

    }

}


//The code in JSONexmaple.json

    {
        "slides": [{
        "name": "zzz",    
        "desc": "xxx"
        }]
    }
```

Comment: add some description about your problem to question!

Answer (score 0):

Use Below Code

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    InputStream is = JSONjava.class.getResourceAsStream( "JSONexample.json");
    String JSONexample = IOUtils.toString( is );

    JSONObject json = (JSONObject) JSONSerializer.toJSON( JSONexample ); 
    JSONArray slides = json.getJSONArray("slides");

    String name = slides.getJSONObject(0).getString("name");
    String desc = slides.getJSONObject(0).getString("desc");

    System.out.println( "Name: " + name );
    System.out.println( "Description: " + desc );

}
```

Comment: So what was the problem ?

Comment: you were using   JSONObject slides = json.getJSONObject("pilot"); this as jsonobject but in your json there is json array of slides so you should use  JSONArray slides = json.getJSONArray("slides");

Comment: Thanks, although I'm not the OP; I asked only because the question contained only code and I was unaware of what the question was about (I still am by the way).

Comment: I changed but the same problema keeps going, "InputStream is= JSONjava.class.getResourceAsStream ( "JSONexample.json"); String JSONexample = IOUtils.toString( is );" i have na error in this line

Answer (score 0):

You probably want `org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils` instead of `sun.misc.IOUtils`.

I say "probably" because you just say "it doesn't work". If you could reduce the need for people to guess what the problem is, you would get more and better help.

If my hypothesis of what your problem is is right:

- If you need to get that library, it's [here](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/).
- It does have a [`IOUtils.toString(InputStream)`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html#toString(java.io.InputStream)), which can be the one you use in your example.
- That method is deprecated, so although you can still use it I recommend to mind the suggestion in the deprecation comment.
- I believe that once you solve this compilation error, the problem mentioned by @sagar676 in a comment to his/her answer will show up at runtime.

Comment: Thanks, i will try that

Comment: I installed the library and i put it in the project but gives me na error in **org**.apache.commons.io.IOUtils

Comment: I just had to reset my computer and that was all, however i now have a error in JSONObject json = (JSONObject) JSONSerializer.toJSON( JSONexample ) in JSONSerializer says i need to create a field

Comment: If the `IOUtils` error is solved and now you have a JSON error, that would be a completely separated issue and you should consider asking a new question. If you do, my advice is to be less vague in explaining the problem and in reporting the errors you get (you should always include the real error message).